# Horizontal alignment of customized label in enumerate environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, enumerate

There is a problem when I customized the label in `enumerate` environment. I used `label=\bfseries{(${\qquad}$)\arabic*.}` but the label will be out of the range of `\textwidth`. Like the following figure:

[image]

However, what I really need is more like this (made in MS Word):

[image]

How can I fix the code?

The MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\Large{\bfseries Exam (I)} \\[0.3cm]
\end{center}

\normalsize
\noindent {\bfseries I. True or False. }
\begin{enumerate}[label=\bf{(${\qquad}$)\arabic*.}]
   \item Statement 1. This is the exam about earth science and there is a long long long sentence. I want a suitable horizontal alignment......
   \item Statement 2. 
\end{enumerate}

\noindent {\bfseries II. Fill in the Blank. }
\begin{enumerate}[label=\bf{\arabic*.}]
    \item Statement 3 \underline{${\qquad}{\qquad}$}.
    \item Statement 4 \underline{${\qquad}{\qquad}$}.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `leftmargin=*` to your settings.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\noindent {\bfseries I. True or False. }
\begin{enumerate}[label={\bfseries (\qquad)\arabic*.},leftmargin=*]
  \item Statement 1. This is the exam about earth science and there is a long long long sentence. 
    I want a suitable horizontal alignment \ldots
  \item Statement 2. 
\end{enumerate}

\noindent {\bfseries II. Fill in the Blank. }
\begin{enumerate}[label={\bfseries\arabic*.}]
  \item Statement 3 \underline{\qquad\qquad}.
  \item Statement 4 \underline{\qquad\qquad}.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

If you wish to reference the items as well, you should add an appropriate `ref=\arabic*` option to the list as well.